# Limits of trig functions

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, derivatives

How can I find the following problems using elementary trigonometry?

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1−\cos x}{x^2}.$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x−\sin x}{x^3}.
$$

Have attempted trig identities, didn't help.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you either do not know or are not allowed to use L'Hospital's rules?

Comment: Taylor series saves you every time. If you don't like that, you can always use half-angle formulas. The first numerator is $2\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}$ and the second is very similar once you write it as $\tan x (1-\cos x)$.

Comment: I am allowed to use L'Hospital's rule!

Comment: @user152739 Then just use the rule a couple of times, it's simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $\cos x = 1-2\sin^2\frac x2$ gives you $$\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2} = \frac{2\sin^2\frac x2}{x^2} = \frac12\left(\frac{\sin\frac x2}{\frac x2}\right)^2.$$

Using similar identities will help with the second limit as well.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT :**
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1−\cos x}{x^2}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1−\cos x}{x^2}\cdot\frac{1+\cos x}{1+\cos x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1−\cos^2 x}{x^2(1+\cos x)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2(1+\cos x)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x\cdot\sin x}{x\cdot x\cdot(1+\cos x)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{1+\cos x}\\
&=1\cdot1\cdot\frac1{1+1}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x−\sin x}{x^3}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x−\sin x}{x^3}\cdot\frac{\cos x}{\cos x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x(1−\cos x)}{x^3\cos x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x(1−\cos x)}{x^3\cos x}\cdot\frac{1+\cos x}{1+\cos x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^3 x}{x^3\cos x(1+\cos x)},\\
\end{align}
where $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1.$

Comment: Should I take the derivative then? I can't seem to get anywhere with it!

Comment: @user152739 No. See my edit for the first one and use the similar way to the second one.

Answer (score 0):

[L'hopital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) is useful in this case, since the limits are of indeterminate form $0/0$. Then, taking the derivative of the numerator and denominator:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1−\cos x}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{2x} = \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}.
$$
which should look more familiar. The second limit is the same deal, except you apply L'hopital's rule 3 times (until the denominator is a constant). See if you can work it out yourself!